# How would you integrate Tibco with Sharepoint 2010?

Tags: sharepoint, tibco

I'm looking at integrating Tibco with Sharepoint 2010 and need to get an understanding of how to go about this. I haven't been able to find anything on Google.

I don't see an adapter for Tibco for Sharepoint so I assume it would need to be manually wired up.

Many thanks!

Comment: TIBCO is a company, SharePoint is a content management system. Clarify your question.

Answer (score 1):

What do you want to integrate?

As Pavel stated, you really need to clarify more. I don't believe there is a SharePoint adapter that is commercially sold by TIBCO at the moment. You could develop your own, but I don't see much of a point.

While SharePoint has become less of a traditional CMS and more of a RAD platform, I can see potential integration points, however I really don't think you would need to write your own adapter.

Fill us in on what exactly it is you're trying to accomplish and I'd be more than happy to provide some insight, as I've worked extensively on both platforms.

Thanks,

Zachary Carter